# Not able to setting thread scope.

Tags: pthreads

I am learning about pthreads,I want to set the scope of a thread so for setting scope I used  pthread_attr_setscope() API but when I try to get scope of a thread using pthread_attr_getscope() API it all ways return me 0 regardless what ever scope I set(either PROCESS_SCOPE/SYSTEM_SCOPE). For more information please find code below.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadid;
    printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    int rc; 
    long t;
    int ret=0;
    int mypolicy=-1;
    int iscope=-1;  

    ret = pthread_attr_init (&attr);  

    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr,SCHED_RR);

    // BOUND behavior - Creating SYSTEM_SCOPE thread 
    ret = pthread_attr_setscope(&attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM); 

    //Unbound behaviour - Creating process scope thread
    ret = pthread_attr_setscope(&attr,PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS); 

    for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
        printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
        printf("Return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        printf("Return value of getschedule policy = %d \n",pthread_attr_getschedpolicy(&attr, &mypolicy));
        printf("policy = %d \n",mypolicy);
        printf("Return value of getscope = %d \n",pthread_attr_getscope(&attr,&iscope));
        printf("scope = %d \n",iscope);

        if (rc){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            _exit(-1);  
        }
    }   

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I don't know why every time I get the same value of 'iscope' regardless what ever scope I set(either PROCESS_SCOPE/SYSTEM_SCOPE).

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't check for errors in your `pthread_attr_setscope` calls.  Put

   ```
   if (ret) perror("pthread_attr_setscope");
   ```

   immediately after both calls, and see what it prints.  (It may be that your OS does not support one or other of the scheduling modes.)
2. You call `pthread_attr_setscope` twice in a row on the same `pthread_attr_t` with two different scope constants.  This cannot possibly be what you want.
3. You need to pass the `pthread_attr_t` as the second argument to `pthread_create`, instead of the `NULL` you have there, for the changed setting to have any effect at all.
4. Once you make that change, the scheduling policy will apply to the just-created thread, but `pthread_attr_getscope` is being called in the main thread.  Move it to `PrintHello` if you want to know the policy for the just-created thread.

Answer (score 0):

- You never used your ret variable, so the gcc compiler complained about that (I used -Wall).
- Pick a scope -- you've set it twice, sequentially, as zwol mentioned
- However, you don't need to use pthread_attr_getscope in the thread itself; the pthread_attr_getscope function simply reports on what's been set in the attribute.
- Use pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr,PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED); - on systems that support multiple contention scopes, this call is needed to get pthread_create to honor the scheduler attribute.  Otherwise, the new thread will simply inherit the main thread's scope.
- If you're using Linux - Linux only supports PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM, so trying to set PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS is, essentially, just ignored